# Partial Template specialization and icc

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Consider the following code:

```
template <class T, class U, class V>
struct Foo { };

template <class T, class U>
struct Foo<T, U, std::integral_constant<int, U::value>> {
  static void print()
  {
    std::cerr << "instantiated";
  }
};

template <class U>
struct Foo<double, U, std::integral_constant<int, U::value>> {
  static void print()
  {
    std::cerr << "instantiated special";
  }
};

struct Bar {
  static const int value = 0;
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  using Baz = Foo<double, Bar, std::integral_constant<int, 0>>;
  Baz::print();

  return 0;
}
```

When I compile this with icc 16.0.1, I get the following message:

```
main.cpp(38): error: more than one partial specialization matches the template argument list of class "Foo<double, Bar, std::integral_constant<int, 0>>"
            "Foo<T, U, std::integral_constant<int, U::value>>"
            "Foo<double, U, std::integral_constant<int, U::value>>"
    Baz::print();
```

With clang 3.7.1 and gcc 5.3.0 this compiles (and "instantiated special" is printed). Is this a bug in icc, or is my code incorrect? To me it seems clear that the second specialization is strictly more specialized than the first; it is identical to the first other than the fact that it locks down the first template parameter.

Edit: I should add: if this is a bug in icc, is there a good workaround?

Comment: Sure looks like a bug in icc to me.

Comment: Could you check if the suggestions in the [comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37216212/partial-template-specialization-and-icc#comment61972971_37216503) fix the problem on ICC, please? Not a complete fix for your issue, of course, just a step forward in the investigation.

Comment: In the actual code, the integer comes from a nested member of U, this in turn gave clang problems, so my colleague shifted from non type to type template parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug in ICC.

---

Both partial specializations match your implementation, so go into the partial template ordering rules on two synthesized functions:

```
template <class T, class U> void f(Foo<T, U, std::integral_constant<int, U::value> ); 
template <class U>          void f(Foo<double, U, std::integral_constant<int, U::value> );
```

The partial ordering rules involve synthesizing new types for each template argument and attempting to do deduction with each overload against the rest. First, we attempt to deduce `U` against `Foo<_U1, _U2, std::integral_constant<int, _U2::value>>`. This fails, since `_U1` doesn't match `double`. So the first overload isn't at least as specialized than the second. Next, we attempt to deduce `T` and `U` against `Foo<double, _U3, std::integral_constant<int, _U3::value>>`. This succeeds with `T=double` and `U=_U3`. So the second overload is at least as specialize as the first.

As a result, the second overload is more specialized than the first. There is a unique most specialized partial partialization, which is the one that should be instantiated (and is by gcc and clang). ICC's failure to do so is a bug.

Comment: Partial ordering and non-deduced contexts at work again... Replacing `U::value` with a deduced `int I` will most likely make things work as expected. It looks like the EDG front-end (most likely used by ICC here) agrees with MSVC and makes neither overload at least as specialized as the other because of the non-deduced context. Worryingly, I tested a non-MSVC-quirks EDG in its `--strict` mode and it still does the same thing. It's 2 on 2 as compilers go. Just great.

Comment: @bogdan Why would that make deduction fail?

Comment: I do agree that it makes no sense for deduction to fail in the second step in your explanation. I was just pointing out that the non-deduced context is most likely the cause of the problem (and I'm very surprised at EDG's behaviour). I'll ask the OP to check if changing `U::value` to `0` (or as suggested above) fixes the problem on ICC.